# code displays video on my PC, but downloads the file when loaded on site server

Tags: video, iframe

The following code works when ran from my PC locally.
When I upload it to the web site server, instead of displaying the video it downloads the file.

id="Video"

Comment: <iframe width="265" height="175" src="images/videomarketing-1.mp4" id="I1" name="I1"> id="Video"</iframe>

Comment: Remove `id="Video"` nothing should be in between `>  </` so it should look like this:`<iframe width="265" height="175" src="images/videomarketing-1.mp4" id="I1" name="I1"> </iframe>`

Comment: removing the id="Video" did not work.... Any other ideas?

Comment: I changed it to the following and it works great...Thanks

Comment: <video width="268" height="175" autoplay>
 <source src="images/videomarketing-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>